# Using @IntDef in a LiveData Observable

Tags: android, android-livedata

I'm looking at how to update some existing code to use the new Android LiveData architectural pattern.  Hopefully the code sample is self explanatory, I'm struggling to get @IntDef / @Interface to work with Live Data.  I'm happy to create methods on the ViewModel for SetAnsweredCorrectly, SetCheated, etc or to create a MutableLiveData property and set it in code, it's just I'm struggling to see how to use anything other than a normal Integer, which loses the type safety.

```
public class QuestionViewModel extends ViewModel {

    public static final int UNANSWERED = 0;
    public static final int ANSWERED_CORRECTLY = 1;
    public static final int ANSWERED_INCORRECTLY = 2;
    public static final int CHEATED = 3;

    @IntDef({UNANSWERED, ANSWERED_CORRECTLY, ANSWERED_INCORRECTLY, CHEATED})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    public @interface AnswerState{}

    private @AnswerState int answeredState;

    public Question()
    {
        this.setAnsweredState(UNANSWERED);
    }

    public @AnswerState int getAnsweredState() {
        return answeredState;
    }

    public void setAnsweredState(@AnswerState int answeredState) {
        this.answeredState = answeredState;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ObservableField<AnswerState> observableAnswer = new ObservableField<>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:
First, you'll need to create a model class that has a property that can be your state only. `e.g.`

```
class State(@AnswerState val state: Int)
```

After that, you can create new `LiveData` objects of this new type you have just created. `e.g.`

```
private val _answerState = MutableLiveData(State(UNANSWERED))
val answerState: LiveData<State>
    get() = _answerState
```

Whenever you need to post your value to the `LiveData` you will do the following

```
_answerState.postValue(State(ANSWERED_CORRECTLY))
```

To observe these values, In your `Activity` class you will register the observers like this

```
viewModel.answerState.observe(this) {
    when (it.state) {
        // The compiler will suggest the remaining branches        
    }
}
```

After that, click on `when` and hit `alt + enter` and the compiler will suggest to add the remaining branches, namely `UNANSWERED, ANSWERED_CORRECTLY, ANSWERED_INCORRECTLY, CHEATED`
[image]

That's it :) The compiler will generate a new branch for each state and you can behave accordingly.